# Unable to get the Sort property of the Range class

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting the above error when performing a sort. I've fully qualified all objects and checked that my variables hold the correct values. The error occurs on the first line:

```
With ws.Columns("A:E").Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("A2:A" & oldLastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange ws.Range("A1:E" & oldLastRow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

It doesn't seem to matter how I refer to the range, each of these gives the same error:

```
With ws.Range("A:E").Sort


With ws.Range("A1:E" & oldLastRow).Sort
```

There is data in each cell of the range and the columns have headers. What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ws.Columns("A:E").Sort` is calling the `Sort` function of a `Range` which is different from the `Sort` class of the worksheet:

[image]

(hit F2 in the VBA editor to get to that screen)

So your code will likely work if you just remove the `.Columns("A:E")` of your snippet e.g.:

```
With ws.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=ws.Range("A2:A" & oldLastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange ws.Range("A1:E" & oldLastRow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

You are already saying what you want to sort with `.SetRange ws.Range("A1:E" & oldLastRow)` so you can see it is a bit redundant to also have it in the `With` statement (as well as generating the error).

PS I get

> Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method